Help finding movie about a boy growing up in/around the 60's
I watched this movie a long time ago, and can't remember much of anything. I know that its generally about a boy growing up a fairly long time ago (I know the movie is old but not sure how old.) 

Either English or American and with a mostly young male cast
I want to say it was probably around the 1960s and filmed in color
The main character has a sister who he doesn't get along with, mostly because of her boyfriend
In the movie someone's house catches on fire and all that is left is rubble
In one scene, a teenage girl lets a group of younger boys peek into her skirt
Near the end or middle of the movie the main family moves, or possibly goes on vacation
The younger brother at one point sees the sister having sex with her boyfriend
I think the movie is rated r, but it might be PG13
Anyone have any ideas??


@Paulie_D Thank you so much:) I've edited the question after looking at how some others were formatted. I appreciate your help!!

Thanks for improving the question; possible answer posted.

This hits a lot of bits in Hope and Glory from 1987. It happens around WWII, though.

Bill Rohan, a young boy living on the outskirts of London experiences the exhilaration of World War II, as seen through the eyes of director John Boorman, who also wrote and produced the autobiographical film. During this period, Bill learns about sex, death, love, hypocrisy, and the faults of adults as he prowls the ruins of bombed houses on Rosehill Avenue. His childlike father is off chasing patriotic dreams of glory from behind a military clerk's typewriter; his teenage sister runs wild; his mother can't cope; and everything in the end will eventually turn out all right.

IIRC the protagonist sees his sister make out with a soldier; their house burns down at some point; and there's a scene where a girl shows her private parts to a bunch of boys. And here's the trailer:



